# Tensorflow neural network has high error even in really easy dataset

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a 1 hidden layer NN for a regression problem. The loss function improves for a few iterations than it gets stuck on a really high error even for a very easy data. Could someone help me find the bug? Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
reuse_weights = 1
n_nodes_hl1 = 10
batch_size  = 200
hm_epochs = 20

# load input from matlab 
input_training = sio.loadmat('xMat.mat')
input_training = input_training['xMat']
input_test = sio.loadmat('xMat.mat')
input_test = input_test['xMat']

# find number of measurements and input length
n_measurements = input_training.shape[0]
input_length = input_training.shape[1]

# current input
data_y = input_training[:, input_length - 1].astype(float)
data_x = input_training[:, 0 : input_length - 1].astype(float)
test_data_y = input_test[:, input_length - 1].astype(float)
test_data_x = input_test[:, 0 : input_length - 1].astype(float)

x = tf.placeholder('float32',[None, input_length - 1])
y = tf.placeholder('float32')

# place holder for Dropout algorithm drop probability
keep_prob = tf.placeholder('float32')

def next_batch(data):
    """
    Return a total of `batch_size` samples from the array `data`. 
    """
    if len(data.shape) == 2:
        idx = np.arange(0, len(data[:,0]))  # get all possible indexes
    else:
        idx = np.arange(0, len(data))  # get all possible indexes

    np.random.shuffle(idx)  # shuffle indexes
    idx = idx[0:batch_size]  # use only `batch_size` random indexes

    if len(data.shape) == 2:
        data_shuffle = [data[i,:] for i in idx]  # get list of `batch_size` random samples
    else:
        data_shuffle = [data[i] for i in idx]  # get list of `batch_size` random samples

    data_shuffle = np.asarray(data_shuffle)  # get back numpy array
    return data_shuffle

def neural_network_model(data, weights, biases, keep_prob):
    layer1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer1)
    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    return output

if reuse_weights:
    weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(sio.loadmat('weights_h1.mat')['weights_h1'], name="weights_h1"),
    'out': tf.Variable(sio.loadmat('weights_out.mat')['weights_out'], name="weights_out")
    }
    biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(sio.loadmat('biases_b1.mat')['biases_b1'], name="biases_b1"),
    'out': tf.Variable(sio.loadmat('biases_out.mat')['biases_out'], name="biases_out")
    }
else: # initialize weights
    weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_length - 1, n_nodes_hl1]), name="weights_h1"),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, 1]), name="weights_out")
    }
    biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]), name="biases_b1"),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="biases_out")
    }

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)[:,0]   
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(prediction - y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    opt = optimizer.minimize(cost)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(weights['h1'])

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs): #training
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(n_measurements/batch_size)):
                _, c, p = sess.run([opt, cost, prediction], feed_dict = {x:next_batch(data_x),\
                y:next_batch(data_y) , keep_prob : 1.0})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'Average loss:', epoch_loss/int(n_measurements/batch_size))

        # prediction
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(prediction - y))

        # Feed 1.0 for keep prob during testing
        print("Training data accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: data_x, y: data_y, keep_prob : 1.0}))
        print("Training data predictions:", prediction.eval({x: data_x[0:5,:], keep_prob : 1.0}))
        print("Training data:",data_y[0:5])
        #print("Test data accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: test_data_x, y: test_data_y, keep_prob : 1.0}))


        # save numpy arrays
        sio.savemat('weights_h1.mat', {'weights_h1': weights['h1'].eval()})
        sio.savemat('biases_b1.mat', {'biases_b1': biases['b1'].eval()})
        sio.savemat('weights_out.mat', {'weights_out': weights['out'].eval()})
        sio.savemat('biases_out.mat', {'biases_out': biases['out'].eval()})

train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: Could you give an example value which the loss functions gets stuck at? If your input data contains large numerical values, this might not be unexpected. You might consider normalizing your data in order to avoid this.

Comment: Do you have a good accuracy ? And if you're using only 1 hidden layer, maybe the objective function is just too complicated to approach it better...

Comment: I've tried a few input data such as rows of 4 random normal samples (hence its not large numerical values). I'm trying to predict the sum of the 4 number (just a mini test which currently does not work). The input data shape is 100000(samples)X5(input and output). The problem is not that its getting stuck rather than very poor accuracy on the above very easy set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the problem was with the data shuffling. The input and response were shuffled differently (two times random shuffle for each epoch) and thus the input data in each epoch did not correspond to the response data.